# Bootstrap image scatter like this site

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a page where a list of images are place like this site:

http://www.journaldemontreal.com

Can anyone suggest anything?

Answer (score 0):

I am a huge fan of google search because with the right keywords, you get the expected output.
See this link: https://codepen.io/ckschmieder/pen/KVaZMW/

```css
body { margin: 0; background: #333; }

.gallery { 
  max-width: 900px;
  padding: .5vw;
  font-size: 0;
  border: 2px solid whitesmoke;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap; 
  flex-flow: row wrap; 
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.gallery div { 
  -webkit-box-flex: auto;
  -ms-flex: auto;
  flex: auto; 
  width: 200px;
  margin: .5vw; 
}
.gallery div img { 
  width: 100%; 
  height: auto; 
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .gallery div { margin: 0; }
  .gallery { padding: 0; }
  
}
```

```html
<section id="main">
  <div class="gallery">
    <div><img src="https://unsplash.it/600/400?image=580"></div>
    <div><img src="https://unsplash.it/500/340?image=870"></div>
    <div><img src="https://unsplash.it/520/400?image=767"></div>
    <div><img src="https://unsplash.it/650/400?image=296"></div>
    <div><img src="https://unsplash.it/620/410?image=168"></div>
    <div><img src="https://unsplash.it/600/450?image=871"></div>
    <div><img src="https://unsplash.it/355/400?image=826"></div>
    <div><img src="https://unsplash.it/620/410?image=168"></div>
    <div><img src="https://unsplash.it/600/450?image=871"></div>
    <div><img src="https://unsplash.it/355/400?image=826"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

FYI: I did not write this, but whoever did, credit goes to them.

It does not look good here, but you should check it on codepen